# Compiling Direct X 11 code on windows 8

Tags: directx-11

I've been trying to run the examples from the book 'Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Direct X 11' by Frank Luna however, no matter what I try I can't seem to get any of the projects to compile.

I've installed the june 2010 SDK as per instructions found here: http://d3dcoder.net/WordPress/

However I'm not sure I've done the rest of the tasks correctly.

Has anyone had any luck trying to run these? I'd like to learn Direct X but without the proper way to compile them I'm pretty much dead in the water.

Comment: what failure messages?

Comment: Currently I have a bunch of the following (I'm using Visual studio 2015 Community Edition):` C2027 use of undefined type 'InitDirect3DApp' Init Direct3D c:\users\beuden\documents\3dgameprog\dvd\code\chapter 4 direct3d initialization\init direct3d\init direct3d.cpp 33`

Answer (score 0):

The include/lib path order for using the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2012 or later is inverted from the traditional order used for VS 2010. You need to modify your project's [VC++ Directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621(v=vs.140).aspx) to account for this.

For x86/Win32 configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
```

For x64 native configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

This is covered in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

You should also read the notes I have about that [book](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx) on my blog. His DirectX 11 book was published just prior to the deprecation of the legacy DirectX SDK, so it's a bit out-of-date on the margins although the core API stuff is fine.

See also [Where is the DirectX SDK (2013 Edition)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx), [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx), [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx), 
[DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx), [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx), and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk.aspx)